# Creating a canvas chain lib

Tags: javascript, canvas

So i'm getting really lazy with always writing out

```
ctx.moveTo(x, y); 
ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
ctx....
```

for multiple lines of canvas code.  Instead, I created a chainable wrapper to handle all of that stuff, albeit, in a not so dynamic way:

```
function CanvasChainer(ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
}

// just a small snippet
CanvasChainer.prototype = {
  beginPath: function () {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    return this;
  },
  closePath: function () {
    this.ctx.closePath();
    return this;
  },
  fillText: function (str, x, y) {
    this.ctx.fillText(str, x, y);
    return this;
  },
  moveTo: function (x, y) {
    this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    return this;
  }
}
```

When I try to attach everything programatically, I keep on getting this error when I try to use `apply` or `call`:

```
Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object
this.ctx[i].apply(this.ctx[i], args);
```

and the code:

```
var _canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  SLICE = Array.prototype.slice,
  _ctx;

if (_canvas.attachEvent && window.G_vmlCanvasManager) {
  G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement( _canvas );
}

_ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');

function CanvasChainer(ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
}

CanvasChainer.prototype = { };

for (var p in _ctx) {
  if (!CanvasChainer.prototype[p] && typeof _ctx[p] === 'function') {
    (function (i) {
      CanvasChainer.prototype[i] = function () {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
          var args = SLICE.call(arguments, 0);
          this.ctx[i].apply(this.ctx[i], args);
        }
        return this;
      }
    }(p))
   }
 }
```

This implementation works when no arguments are needed (ie. ctx.beginPath()).  I also only care about attaching available functions.

Comment: Use Lea Verou's chainvas. http://leaverou.me/chainvas/

Comment: thanks gerben.  I'll have to take a deeper look at chainvas, but the kangax found the solution for this particular problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you call method in context of `HTMLRenderingContext`?

Replace:

```
this.ctx[i].apply(this.ctx[i], args);
```

with:

```
this.ctx[i].apply(this.ctx, args);
```

Comment: ah, nice catch kangax!  that did the trick to render everything.

Answer (score 0):

the better code:

```
for (var p in _ctx) {
  if (!CanvasChainer.prototype[p] && typeof _ctx[p] === 'function') {
      CanvasChainer.prototype[p] = function (p) {
        return function () {
          return this.ctx[p].apply(this.ctx, arguments) || this;
        };
      }(p);
   }
 }
```